# How to test update method with junit 5 and mockito with exception handling in the service layer

Tags: java, spring-boot, mockito, junit5

I am starting with Mockito to do unit tests.
I have seen several examples of how a unit test can be carried out but it does not work for me since when I pass the object to search to check if it exists and modify it, the exception is thrown and the test is interrupted.

When this line is executed:
**BDDMockito.given(syndromeTypeServiceMock.modifySyndromeType(synTypeMock)).willReturn(synTypeMockEspect)**;
It enters the method in the Service and when validating with the mock, by not going to the database to look for the record, it returns null or empty and the following validation raises the exception.
How can I validate this exception with Mockito so that it passes the test?

Thansk in advance!

```
@ExtendWith(MockitoExtension.class)
public class SyndromeTypeServiceTest {

    Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    
    @Mock
    SyndromeTypeRepository syndromeTypeRepository;
    @Mock
    SyndromeTypeTransRepository syndromeTypeTransRepository;
    @InjectMocks
    SyndromeTypeServiceImpl syndromeTypeServiceMock;
    
    @Test
    public void test_modify_SyndromeType_when_synTransId_exist() throws PersistenceException {
        LOGGER.info("test_modify_SyndromeType_when_synTransId_exist >>");
        

        SyndromeType synTypeMock = SyndromeType.builder()
                                                .synTypeId(10)
                                                .synTypeName("Musculoesquelético.")
                                                .lanCode("es")
                                                .synTypeTransId(10)
                                                .build();
        
        SyndromeType synTypeMockEspect = SyndromeType.builder()
                                                .synTypeId(10)
                                                .synTypeName("Musculoesquelético.")
                                                .lanCode("es")
                                                .synTypeTransId(10)
                                                .build();

        BDDMockito.given(syndromeTypeServiceMock.modifySyndromeType(synTypeMock)).willReturn(synTypeMockEspect);

        assertEquals(synTypeMock.getSynTypeTransId(), synTypeMockEspect.getSynTypeTransId());
        assertEquals(synTypeMock.getSynTypeId(), synTypeMockEspect.getSynTypeId());
        assertEquals(synTypeMock.getSynTypeName(), synTypeMockEspect.getSynTypeName());

        LOGGER.info("<< test_modify_SyndromeType_when_synTransId_exist");
        
    }
    
}
```

Service layer

```
@Service
@Transactional
public class SyndromeTypeServiceImpl implements SyndromeTypeService {

    Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(getClass());
    
    final SyndromeTypeRepository syndromeTypeRepository;
    final SyndromeTypeTransRepository syndromeTypeTransRepository;
    
    public SyndromeTypeServiceImpl(SyndromeTypeRepository syndromeTypeRepository,
            SyndromeTypeTransRepository syndromeTypeTransRepository) {
        this.syndromeTypeRepository = syndromeTypeRepository;
        this.syndromeTypeTransRepository = syndromeTypeTransRepository;
    }

    @Override
    public List<SyndromeType> renderSyndromeTypes(List<SyndromeTypeTransEntity> synTypesEtts){
        LOGGER.info("Rendering SyndromeTypeEntity results");
        List<SyndromeType> synTypes = new ArrayList<SyndromeType>(0);

        if(null != synTypesEtts) {
            synTypesEtts.stream()
                .forEach(
                    s -> {
                            synTypes.add(
                                    SyndromeType.builder()
                                                .synTypeId(s.getSynTypeEtt().getSynTypeId())
                                                .synTypeName(s.getSynTypeName())
                                                .lanCode(s.getLanCodeEtt().getLanCode())
                                                .synTypeTransId(s.getSynTypeTransId())
                                                .build()
                                    );
                });
            
        }
        
        return synTypes;
    }

    @Override
    public SyndromeType modifySyndromeType(SyndromeType synType) throws PersistenceException {
        LOGGER.info("modifySyndromeType >>");
        
        Optional<SyndromeTypeTransEntity> synTypeEtt = java.util.Optional.empty();
        
        if(null != synType.getSynTypeTransId()) {
            synTypeEtt = syndromeTypeTransRepository.findById(synType.getSynTypeTransId()); 
        }

        if(!synTypeEtt.isPresent() || synTypeEtt.isEmpty()) {
            throw new PersistenceException(ErrorMessage.RECORD_NOT_EXIST.name());
        }
        
        SyndromeTypeTransEntity synTypeTrans = SyndromeTypeTransEntity.builder()
                                                        .lanCodeEtt(LanguageEntity.builder()
                                                                         .lanCode(synType.getLanCode())
                                                                         .build())
                                                        .synTypeName(synType.getSynTypeName())
                                                        .build();
        
        synTypeTrans = syndromeTypeTransRepository.save(synTypeTrans);
        
        List<SyndromeType> synTypesTO = this.renderSyndromeTypes(List.of(synTypeTrans));
        
        SyndromeType synTypeTO = synTypesTO.isEmpty() ? null : synTypesTO.get(0);
        
        LOGGER.info("<< modifySyndromeType");
        return synTypeTO;
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to verify that your method throws an exception? Perhaps you're looking for something like `assertThatThrownBy`?

Comment: Why are all your test fields called `*Mock`? If you only have mocks, you are not testing anything. Hint: `@InjectMocks` does not create a mock, but a real instance; with other mocks injected as needed. Since `syndromeTypeServiceMock` is not a mock (but a real instance), you cannot stub its methods with `given().thenReturn()`. `SyndromeType synTypeMock` ← not a mock either

Comment: @voidvoid checking the exception would be another test. What I'm trying to test is to return the registry to be modified

Comment: @knittl It may be the confusion of so many tutorials that I have seen on how to validate the service layer and I have mixed some concepts. -->

Comment: I understand that @InjectMocks injects the real instance, SyndromeType objects synTypeMock understood that they are Mock since they are not real in the DB because of the Mock suffix

Comment: Your service isn't a mock but you are registering behavior on it, this will not work nor is the way to do it. You should register behavior on the mocks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mockito mock ojects (created with `Mockito.mock` or `@Mock`) by default always return `null` or empty collections. If you require them to return a different value, you have to stub the methods.

`@InjectMocks` on the other hand creates a *real* instance of your interface/class and injects the mock objects as dependencies. A real instance's methods cannot be stubbed – and it wouldn't make sense really, because this is the class that you usually want to exercise in your test.

This means that if you want to test your service, you need to make sure that you are calling the real service and that any methods it calls return a useful value.

The following block calls `findById` on the *repository* (not the service), for which you have created a mock object, but never stubbed any methods.

```
if(null != synType.getSynTypeTransId()) {
   synTypeEtt = syndromeTypeTransRepository.findById(synType.getSynTypeTransId()); 
}
```

The repository's method can be stubbed as follows in your test:

```
when(syndromeTypeTransRepository.findById(10)) // the id passed to the service
    .thenReturn(Optional.of(...)); // a value that makes sense for your test
```

The second call to the repository must be stubbed as well:

```
synTypeTrans = syndromeTypeTransRepository.save(synTypeTrans);
```

A sufficient stub implementation is probably to simply return the argument itself:

```
when(syndromeTypeTransRepository.save(any()))
    .thenReturn(AdditionalAnswers.returnsFirstArg());
```

After you have set up the stubbed calls in your test method, you must then call the *real* method of your class (if you are not calling the real method, then what are you testing!?)

```
final SyndromeType actualType = syndromeTypeServiceMock.modifySyndromeType(synType);
```

And then assert the correct value being returned:

```
assertEquals(expectedType, actualType); // if SynType implement equals()
```

or

```
// without equals() properties need to be compared manually
assertEquals(10, actualType.getSynTypeTransId());
assertEquals(10, actualType.getSynTypeId());
assertEquals("Musculoesquelético.", actualType.getSynTypeName());
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @knittle, he has been able to correct the test and the most important thing is that for each action in the method to be tested, a mock must be performed. This is the modification of the test.

```
@Test
public void test_modify_SyndromeType_when_synTransId_exist() throws PersistenceException {
    LOGGER.info("test_modify_SyndromeType_when_synTransId_exist >>");
    
    SyndromeTypeTransEntity synTypeTrans = SyndromeTypeTransEntity.builder()
                                                        .synTypeTransId(10)
                                                        .synTypeName("Musculoesquelético.")
                                                        .lanCodeEtt(LanguageEntity.builder()
                                                                         .lanCode("es")
                                                                         .lanName("Español")
                                                                         .build())
                                                        .synTypeEtt(SyndromeTypeEntity.builder().synTypeId(10).build())
                                                        .build();
    
    
    when(syndromeTypeTransRepository.findById(10)) // the id passed to the service
                                    .thenReturn(Optional.of(synTypeTrans)); // a value that makes sense for your test
    
    when(syndromeTypeTransRepository.save(any())) 
                                    .thenReturn(synTypeTrans); 

    SyndromeType synType = SyndromeType.builder()
                                            .synTypeId(10)
                                            .synTypeName("Musculoesquelético.")
                                            .lanCode("es")
                                            .synTypeTransId(10)
                                            .build();

    final SyndromeType actualSynType = syndromeTypeService.modifySyndromeType(synType);

    assertEquals(10, actualSynType.getSynTypeTransId());
    assertEquals(10, actualSynType.getSynTypeId());
    assertEquals("Musculoesquelético.", actualSynType.getSynTypeName());

    LOGGER.info("<< test_modify_SyndromeType_when_synTransId_exist");
    
}
```